# GROUP BY date and sum together forward yes but backward no

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
PEOPLE, DATE, DELETED
Amanda, 2015-03-01, Null
Ray, 2015-03-01, Null
Moe, 2015-04-01, Null
Yan, 2015-05-01, Null
Bee, 2015-05-05, 2015-06-12
```

now I need to group it and sum it with months like this:

```
March: 2 people
April: 3
May: 5
June: 5
July: 4
```

so new people should not be counted in previous month but they should be in next months for my range (January - June). And if man is DELETED, he should be counted together with another people last time in month when he has been deleted.

How to write query for this?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/ ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

This can be at least solved using running totals. This just the outline how to do it, you'll need to do some work for the actual solution:

```
select people, date, 1 as persons from yourtable
union all
select people, deleted, -1 as persons from yourtable where deleted is not null
```

Then do a running total of this data, so that you sum the +-1 persons -field, and that should give you the amount of people that are there so far.

For the events happening in the middle of the month, you'll have to adjust the date to be the start of that or the next month whichever way you want them to be calculated.

If you need also those months when no changes happened, you'll probably need a table that contains the first day of each month for the biggest range of dates you'll ever need, for example 1.1.2000 - 1.12.2100.